# Товарищи знатоки, помогите с вопросом по virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, копирование

устанавливаю новую машину, общий буфер обмена задан двунаправленный, но между гостевой ос и хостом не копируется/вставляется текст. Помогите исправить, пожалуйста[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Буфер обмена на консоль во фреймбуфере не распространяется.

Переводите консоль на TTY (и цепляйтесь к ней терминалом) или подключайтесь по SSH

Comment: а разве он работает в режиме установки ос на virtualbox? Я имею ввиду,если ос еще без начинки

Comment: обычно есть способ или перенаправить TTY, или запустить sshd во время установки, изучайте ваш дистр

Comment: спасибо  большое <3